# Wave equation of a free string with force applied at one end in 1D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, continuum-mechanics

Consider a string in free space initially occupying $x \in [0, L]$ that is  stationary at $t=0$. Let a force $F(t)$ be applied at the left most particle of the string, i.e. the particle that is initially at $x=0$. What would be the dynamics of the system?

I know that:
$$E\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + f(x,t) = \rho\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$$
If $u(0, t)$ can be determined, the displacement vector can easily be calculated. My problem is that I cannot seem to do that. How do I approach this? The only way I can see is to express $f(x,t)$ in terms of $F(t)$ with the help of the step function, and take the Fourier transform in both dimensions. The displacement vector can then be expressed in terms of a convolution.

Comment: This will be equivalent to a string hanging from the $x=0$ end in a gravitational field. That's a standard and easily Googlable problem.

Comment: @JohnRennie the string is free to move, and the force is applied only at one side of the string. It is trivial to solve the problem when you have a constant force acting on each particle of the string. Also note that the force is time dependent.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't notice you'd written the force as $F(t)$